# Can one complete a topological space induced by a family of pseudometrics?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose I have a set $X$ and a family $\{d_i\vert i \in I\}$ of pseudometrics on $X$. For each pseudometric $d_i$ you get a metric space by taking $X_i = X/\sim$ where $x\sim y \iff d_i(x,y)=0$. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the initial topology induced by the projections $p_i : X \to X_i$. Let's further say that the family is definite, i.e. $d_i(x,y)=0 \, \forall i \implies x=y$. Can we always construct a completion of $X$ that completes all $X_i$?

Is there a name for topological spaces that can be obtained this way or can every topological space be constructed by this?  What if every pseudometric is complete?

This question came to my mind when trying to generalize [this approach to Caratheodorys measurability criterion and theorem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.2270v1.pdf) on non-$\sigma$-finite spaces by setting $d_A(X,Y) = m^*(A\cap (X\triangle Y))$ for every $A$ with $m^*(A)<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is rather simple. In general you can always give a completion to X. If $Y_j$ is the completion of $X_j$ and $i_j:X_j \to Y_j$ the corresponding embedding, let $Y=\prod_{j\in I} Y_j$, and $i:X \to Y, \,
x \mapsto (i_j\circ p_j  (x) )_{j \in I}$. Then $\overline{i(X)}=Y$ and $Y$ should have the desired properties.